# How to send push notifications to Google Firebase web application

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

Can anybody provide information on how to setup push notifications for a chrome web application?

How to setup topics, create new topics, delete topics and what the syntax would be.

I searched the internet using what tools we have and come up with nothing.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you consulted their getting started: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Answer (score 0):

There is no client-side API for web applications to subscribe to topics. You can use the REST API, but that requires running a trusted process (i.e. on a server). See my answer here for details: [How to subscribe to topics with web browser using Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40389335/how-to-subscribe-to-topics-with-web-browser-using-firebase-cloud-messaging)

Note that in general there is no API to create/delete topics. Topics are automatically created when you subscribe to them or send a message to them.