# How to implement FCM with topics in a PWA made without frameworks

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, mqtt

I have an PWA app made without frameworks.
I'm trying to implement the FCM to send notifications (also when the app is in background - service workes) to all devices that allowed it, but i only managed to send it to devices that i know the access tokens, i didn't figured out how to subscribe devices to topics...
I need to create the topics on firebase console? Or i just need to subscribe devices to them?
How could i do this in a secure way?

Found this answer here on stack overflow, but i still have doubts.

[How to subscribe to topics with web browser using Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40389335/how-to-subscribe-to-topics-with-web-browser-using-firebase-cloud-messaging)

Comment: Topics are automatically created when a user subscribes to them. For web clients you do that by calling the REST API as I answered in the question you linked, which you do from a server since it requires specifying the FCM server key. I updated my linked answer to be a bit clearer.

Comment: Thanks Frank! I did another API on my server that handles the subscriptions, now everything seems to be working.

Comment: should i subscribe to a topic every time my PWA loads? to guarantee that the user will receive the notification

Comment: Nope, you only need to subscribe each token once. But you will need to resubscribe when the token changed, somethint that the mobile SDKs handle behind the scenes I think.