# Firebase javascript v9 getMessaging().subscribeToTopic() undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using firebase javascript api v9 in my react project and i am using the code below as suggested by the oficial [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/send-multiple)

```
    import { getMessaging } from "firebase/messaging";
    
    // These registration tokens come from the client FCM SDKs.
    const registrationTokens = [
      'fcm_token_string'
    ];
    
    // Subscribe the devices corresponding to the registration tokens to the topic
    getMessaging().subscribeToTopic(registrationTokens, topic)
      .then((response) => {
        // See the MessagingTopicManagementResponse reference documentation [enter link description here][1]for the contents of response.
        console.log('Successfully subscribed to topic:', response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error subscribing to topic:', error);
      });
```

However, despite of doing exactly what the documation of firebase api v9 says, I am getting undefined when accessing getMessaging().subscribeToTopic function.

I am wondering if this function was moved to another component and the documentation has become outdated.

I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to subscribe a **web** client to a topic from within the client-side code (see [How to subscribe to topics with web browser using Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40389335/how-to-subscribe-to-topics-with-web-browser-using-firebase-cloud-messaging)). So that code you got from the documentation is supposed to run on the server, using the Firebase Admin SDK for Node.js, which still uses the namespaced `...subscribeToTopic()` syntax.

Comment: Thank you @Frank. Everything gets clear with your answer.